# UpdatePanel doesnt reflect changes if the function is called by delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Having the following setup, why the update panel doesnt reflect the label text change if u change it throught delegates/eventhandlers? How would you make it work?

Test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test"
    EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
        EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Example label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="btnChange" OnClick="btnChange_Click" runat="server" Text="Change">
            </asp:Button>
            <table id="tableMessage" runat="server" style="display: none" >
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lb5" runat="server" Text="Warning"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <asp:Label ID="lbMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" AccessKey="a" Font-Bold="True" Text="Ok"
                            Width="125px" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" AccessKey="C" Font-Bold="True" Text="Cancel"
                            Width="125px" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOKError" runat="server" Text="OK" Style="display: none" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
                ID="ModalPopupMessage" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnOKError" PopupControlID="tableMessage"
                OkControlID="btnOKError" CancelControlID="btnOKError" DropShadow="true">
            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using AsistenciasCapadatos;

public partial class Test : Page
{

    private EventHandler OkButtonClick
    {
        get { return SessionActual.Get<EventHandler>("OkButtonClick"); }

        set { SessionActual.Set("OkButtonClick", value); }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageConfirm("Do you want to change label?", btnChange1_Click);
    }
    protected void btnChange1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//the text property changes correctly but the updatepanel doesnt reflect it...viewstate ajax bug?
        Label1.Text = "Change1"; 
    }
    protected void btnChange2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Change2";
    }


    protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = "Change1"; //this way works
        OkButtonClick.Invoke(sender, e); //this doesnt
    }
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void MessageConfirm(string message, EventHandler btnclick)
    {
        OkButtonClick = btnclick;
        lbMessage.Text = message;
        ModalPopupMessage.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If i add a watch to Label1.Text i see how its value changes inside btnChange1_Click but its value returns to the original when it returns to the btnOk_Click :S, in theory they are inside the same thread so whats happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i solved it changing the following lines:

```
Page.GetType().InvokeMember(OkButtonClick.Method.Name, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, Page, new []{sender, e}); //this works
//OkButtonClick.Invoke(sender, e); //this doesnt
```

But i would like to know WHY it does work this way...so if anyone can explain it i will grant the answer to him/her instead...

Answer (score 0):

did u tried debugging what value you get for `OkButtonClick` when `btnChange_Click` call finishes..

```
(new EventHandler(btnChange1_Click)).Invoke(sender, e); //this should work
```

Comment: At the end of btnChange_Click it has assigned btnChange1_Click and in the btnOk_Click when its called it has assigned btnChange1_Click too.

Comment: The code you put works because it calls directly to the btnChange1_Click, the thing is getting it to work with the handler/delegate passed to the function...